# How do I remove specfic OptionData from Dropdown?

Tags: unity, c#

How would I remove one of the elements from the dropdown? For example, how would I remove Sprites? Here is my code:

```
public Dropdown researchFeatureDropDown;
researchFeatureDropDown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData("Sprites"));
researchFeatureDropDown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData("Scrolling - 2000"));
```

Comment: The options property is a simple list, so I suggest you take a look at the [documentation for List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx). More concretely, the remove method. This may require you to store a reference to the object you are adding to the options.

Answer (score 1):

The `options` property is a `List<OptionData>`, and there are no other obvious methods for removing items on the [`Dropdown` type itself](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown.html) (other than `ClearOptions`, which empties the entire list).

Based on the principle of good API design that says one should make an API easy to use correctly and hard to misuse, it's reasonable to then conclude that you just manipulate the `options` list directly (especially since that's how you put items in the list in the first place`).

Thus, you can [use `RemoveAt` to remove an item by index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx), or [`Remove` to remove it if you have the actual item object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx) itself.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Dropdown itself, but the scripting API does list a DestroyItem method as well. Doesn't this allow for removing individual elements?

Comment: Possibly; the documentation claims you should override it to implement a *different* way to destroy an item, so it doesn't sound like it's what you are supposed to call from outside the Dropdown class hierarchy to do so (it's also protected, so you *can't* call it unless you're within a Dropdown subclass).

Comment: It lists it both under protected and public (which is rather I odd I must say). I just couldn't really imagine this not having any base functionality (I read that part of the docs as well), as it seems rather trivial, especially when they do provide a default ClearOptions